# What type to specify for event handlers tied to multiple fields?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React form with dynamic fields based on [this tutorial](https://www.cluemediator.com/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-reactjs). It needs to be modified to be TypeScript compatible. I'm getting this error:

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ makeModel: string; year: string; }'."

```
 const handleCarChange = (e: any, index: number) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...carList];
    list[index][name] = value;  // TODO fix this typescript error
    setCarList(list);
  };
```

Comment: share `carList` array

Comment: for event, you can `SyntheticEvent` type from `React`

Answer (score 0):

For using types with click handlers, you can try using MouseEvent from `React`. Not sure if this solves the typescript error though. It looks different.

```js
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';

const handleCarChange = (e: MouseEvent, index: number) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   const list = [...carList];
   list[index][name] = value;  // TODO fix this typescript error
   setCarList(list);
};
```

Further reading.
https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/events/

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is bad. And this is only my opinion.

**Why ?**

First of all, this line `const list = [...carList];` does not make any sense.

Here, author of tutorial still mutates the array

```
list[index][name] = value;
```

Consider next example:

```js
const list = [{ name: 1 }]
const newList = [...list]
newList[0]["name"] = 2

list // [{name: 2}]
```

You should never mutate the state. This line `[...list]` only creates shallow copy. It just new reference to whole array, but each element in the array still have the same reference.

Let's go back to your problem.

```js
type Fn = (args: any) => any

type ChangeHandler = ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>

type WithIndex<T extends Fn> = (e: Parameters<T>[0], index: number) => void

const Component = () => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState<State>([{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);

  const handleCarChange: WithIndex<ChangeHandler> = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    const newList = inputList.map((elem: Entity, i: number) =>
      i === index ? {
        ...elem,
        [name]: value
      } : elem)

    setInputList(newList);
  };

  return (
    <input
      onChange={e => handleCarChange(e, 0)}
    />
  )
}
```

Pls keep in mind, for any mouse handler you alway can use built in types like `ChangeEventHandler`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCAFigHYDmSAogG5IkwASpAJgDZJTYCuAzkgMowUMJNiKkKNOvAC%20cAGZQIIOAHIoqDKoCwAKD0wAnmCRxK9YEbgBeXHrgLgUHjAByKEEgBccF1GDkANz2cKwoLu6ePn4BZMG6MnoGxqaCwqa25jCWhgDaALpJukYmcABiJDZwABQoUGQ8PqSGAJQ2AHxwzUUlpuLkSEwkbBxV-ZK09EMjUAA8DAAqALIAMgCSJGBcMJTsnvTtPSlwAOqWhBvMSAAeswtwNyLDPOUknbbV3nAACnUeSCJnHd2rkAAz5bABK7XHwkLggABGHDa1k61AgwGYRTQEBILgIykgJGkVWqKM6OBCOLx8FyAS2MBWwBc2D4MA2DKZLnyVV4AiEIlmaRE7WquTw8icEX%20PgARLLsGFpVE4PK4DJ8i14lTcfjiMN2Pg6uMvmcYBdhjdZibpuwoO8aqI4FCbuS7LoHA5qfi8CR-thqChWFxTHJbEgAHRCeoA7Uez3e%20DEgDuXPgtnp2zTEZAKDA1U%20ex8WRykNh8KRUHJIU9zps1gzluucAA-O7a7WI12kHtMDWO7k-Z58j5A8GkP2HHIfD2kCAWkVa2yOVnmTBqim01qQjI4w4NDAuFBKtV%207NMzBJ3BcSbrDgMp19SMjVATZ9sKCWol4w4APSHeMFwSIo9ETUI1yqcU4CHL4AEZ1UKXQwM3CDbFyLsI1YNdEJQlwwXyXJZRg2UeVsAAmIosPxX9fzgcUYJ8MiNSAA)

If you want to update your state please refer to official redux [patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)